# Why is there no ARCore when I added the ARCore suppor?

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

I'm a hop, skip, and jump away from publishing my new AR Game for Android.  I originally wrote the AR Game for Unity using Google ARCore.  Now when I'm ready to build the game for testing and final release, I end up with an error "Missing Unity Engine ARCore support.  Please ensure that the Unity project has the 'Player Settings > XR Settings > ARCore Supported' checkbox enabled." This error is the one that's been bugging me the most because even though I enabled the ARCore Supported checkbox, I still get this error.  The other included screenshots shows my XR settings and GoogleAR settings.  I only want it to continue using only Google ARCore SDK and not the built in Unity XR system, but I don't know how?

[image: Player Settings showing that ARCore supported under XR has been checked]

[image: Console log of my errors remaining. The one that's giving the most trouble is the one highlighted]

[image: Project settings for Google ARCore showing that AR Required has been selected]

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am facing the same problem :(

Comment: Same issue here, got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Hey @Pankti and @aymusbond.  So I realized that selecting ARCore required button under GoogleAR Core actually uses Google SDK.  What I had was AR Foundation set up in my code, and you can't use both at the same time.  To use AR Foundation, you would have to go to XR section of Project Settings and then select AR Core.